# Finding the equation of a plane given a point and a perpendicular line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vectors

Problem:

The plane containing the point $( 1, -5, 8)$ and orthogonal to the line given by
these three equations:
\begin{align*} 
x &= -3 + 15t \\
y &= 14 - t \\
z &= 9 - 3t
\end{align*}

Answer:

One of the general forms of a plane is:
$$ A(x-x_0) + B(y - y_0) + C(z - z_0) = 0 $$
In this case, we have:
\begin{align*} 
A &= 15 \\
B &= -1 \\
C &= -3 \\
15( x - 1) + -1(y + 5) + -3(z - 8) &= 0 \\
15x - 15 - y - 5 - 3z + 24 &= 0 \\
15x  - y - 3z + 4 &= 0
\end{align*}

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @AnotherUser If you could post your comment as an answer, I could accept the question and close it.

Comment: I can't. It's against our policy to answer a solution-verification question with a simple "Yes, it is correct".

Comment: @AnotherUser I did not know about the policy. Thank  you for telling me about it.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.